# Can i call a stored procedure through a view in Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Tags: function, stored-procedures, view, azure-sql-database, dynamic-pivot

I have a dynamic pivot stored proc which needs to be called from view, is it possible in Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
AS
DECLARE @pivv NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivv=COALESCE(@pivv+',','')+ QUOTENAME(DIVISION) from [dbo].[sales_table] GROUP BY DIVISION

IF ISNULL(@pivv, '')<>''
    SET @Query='SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT STOREID, DIVISION  TYP,   SALES VAL from [dbo].[sales_table] 
        )x pivot (MAX(VAL) for TYP in ('+@pivv+')) as xx'

IF ISNULL(@Query, '')<>''
EXEC (@Query)
GO
```

Comment: What have you tried now? If it failed, what's the error message?

Comment: Tried OpenQuery but it is not supported, as the output is dynamic unable to come to a conclusion

Comment: Looking at your SP, it seems you can easily avoid dynamic query. Instead taking the comma separated string @pivv, you can declare a table variable to insert divisions. Then instead of dynamic sql forming, you can just do a in or join that table var. And next convert the SP into a table valued udf. Finally instead of using crazy openquery in your view, just do a simple udf call just like another table.

Comment: or even simpler the query can be done using PARTITION BY Division in single statement

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain this a bit detail, please?

Comment: @nani2019 The options to call an SP from SQL Server are OPENROWSET / OPENQUERY. 
Both are not supported on Azure SQL Database.
So, No - you cannot call an SP from a view in Azure SQL database as of today.

However, as suggested above, you can convert the logic from your SP into a Table valued function and call the function from your view instead.

If you can post some raw data and expected outcome from your SP, we can help you convert it into a TVF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer :

when below proc is executed, it creates a view directly and this proc can be triggered through an elastic job infrequent intervals or by checking whenever a new division is added to the source table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
AS
DECLARE @pivv NVARCHAR(MAX),@Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivv=COALESCE(@pivv+',','')+ QUOTENAME(DIVISION) from [dbo].[sales_table] GROUP BY DIVISION

IF ISNULL(@pivv, '')<>''
    SET @Query='CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT STOREID, DIVISION  TYP,   SALES VAL from [dbo].[sales_table] 
        )x pivot (MAX(VAL) for TYP in ('+@pivv+')) as xx'

IF ISNULL(@Query, '')<>''
EXEC (@Query)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nani - I wanted to extend what my colleagues (Kalyan and Krishnendu) have shared and provide and answer with regard to Azure SQL (RTM) 12.0.2000.8 supporting DMVs. Azure SQL Database (Single Instance) does support user DMVs but only the [System Dynamic Management Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views?view=sql-server-ver15#in-this-section). Your options are to leverage Azure SQL Database Managed Instance or SQL Server on an Azure VM, as these SQL deployment options offer a near on-premise experience, where Azure SQL Database (Single Instance) offers a subset of functionality. All three of these are running the same (12.0.2000.8) build. The key to identifying which 12.x deployment will work for this scenario is to look at the [@SERVERPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) values:

> ```
>   SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS "Engine Edition", 
>   SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS "Edition",
> ```

[image]

I ran the above query on an Azure SQL Database (Single Instance), as it is identified as `Engine Edition = 5` (SQL Database). If you run this same query against an Azure SQL Database Managed Instance (or any SQL database instance in Azure for that matter) you will see that `Product Version = 12.0.2000.8` is the same across all instances but the *Engine Edition* will not, and this is why your solution will work on some RTM *product version* 12.0.2000.8 instances and not others. If this runs in an on-premise SQL Server instance and you want it to run as-is in Azure, you will need an SQL Server instance deployed to an Azure VM and is an IaaS option. Azure SQL Database Managed Instance is the PaaS option but, the T-SQL between the two specific deployment types has some slight differences as detailed: [T-SQL differences between SQL Server & Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server)

In conclusion, the *Product Version* @SERVERPROPERTY alone cannot determine support for a given piece of functionality. You will need to include the *Engine Edition* @SERVERPROPERTY as well. With this, you can be specific to certain discussion points around support for desired functionality, etc.

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS "Product Version", 
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS "Product Level", 
    SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS "Engine Edition", 
    SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS "Edition",
    @@Version AS "Version";
```

Regards,
Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the detail, I fond the answer to my question.